# Steam won't start with LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' steam

Tags: nvidia, steam

Running a BFG Tech GT 7600 OC.

```
rubicon-iii@rubicon-iii:~$ LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
/bin/bash: /home/rubicon-iii/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /bin/bash)
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1482202200)
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Comment: What is `$LIB` supposed to be? if it's a shell variable, then remember it will not be expanded when inside single quotes

Comment: An even more interesting question is: Why are you doing that?

Comment: Why am I running such an old card? It's what I have on-hand. I'm not allowed a mid-high-tier card, and my budget is under $100 (despite the fact that the 7600 OC is $140 in today's market).